# The subdocument is not initialized when the parent document is created. Nestjs/mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, nestjs

When creating a user, the subdocument is not initialized with default values. I only get the user object without the ecdsa field. Can you tell me where I could have made a mistake?

*P.S. I want the Ecdsa to be part of the user model, not the user model to have the ID of this document. Is it possible?*

User schema:

```
@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({required: true, unique: true })
  tgId: number;

  @Prop({default: "anonymus"})
  tgUsername: string;

  @Prop({default: Date.now()})
  registrationDate: Date;

  @Prop({default: () => ({})})
  ecdsa: Ecdsa;
}

export type UserDocument = User & mongoose.Document;
export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

Ecdsa schema:

```
@Schema()
export class Ecdsa {
  @Prop({default: 0}) //doesn't works
  operatorsCount: number;

  @Prop({
    type: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'UserOperator'
    }],
    default: []
  })
  operators: UserOperator[];

  @Prop({default: 'test'}) //doesn't works
  test: string;
}

export type EcdsaDocument = Ecdsa & mongoose.Document;
export const EcdsaSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Ecdsa);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this method is correct, but it works for me. Now ecdsa object inside User initialized when user created.

I just changed to:

```
@Prop({type: EcdsaSchema,
    default: () => ({})})
  ecdsa: EcdsaDocument;
```